# Multiple documents having equal search score in MongoDB Atlas Search

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, non-relational-database, mongodb-atlas-search

#### Is there a way to boost score for exact match in Atlas search?

I'm having issues getting the right/best translation for 'hi' from English to French. After some debugging I discovered that the first three(3) documents returned from my aggregation has the same score of '2.362138271331787' each.

I'm expecting 'hi' to have a higher score since it has an exact match with the same search query, but 'it’s his' and 'his' seems to have the same score with 'hi'.

Here's my search query:

```js
const searchOption= [
  {
    $search: {
      text: {
        query: 'hi',
        path: 'english',
      },
    },
  },
  { $project: {  _id: 0, french: 1, english: 1, score: { $meta: "searchScore" } } },
  { $limit: 5 },
];

const result = await Greetings.aggregate(searchOption, { cursor: { batchSize: 5 } }).toArray();
```

Here's are the documents returned. The list is ordered by search score:

```json
[
  {
    "english": "it’s his",
    "french": "c'est le sien",
    "score": 2.362138271331787
  },
  {
    "english": "hi",
    "french": "salut",
    "score": 2.362138271331787
  },
  {
    "english": "his",
    "french": "le sien",
    "score": 2.362138271331787
  },
  {
    "english": "it’s his failure to arrange his",
    "french": "c'est son incapacité à organiser son",
    "score": 2.2482824325561523
  },
  {
    "english": "it’s his failure to arrange his time",
    "french": "c'est son incapacité à organiser son temps",
    "score": 2.0995540618896484
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation of Atlas Search and the solution is mentioned here:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/autocomplete/#limitations

The `lucene.keyword` analyzer on a `string` type is so helpful for exact matches in scenarios where score fidelity is essential.

Basically, the path english should be defined in the index definition as both autocomplete and string, like:

```js
[
  {"type": "string"},
  {"type": "autocomplete"}
]
```

The above assumes that you are not using a language analyzer for autocomplete or string, which is probably not ideal for string.

Then, on the query side, you want a `compound` query where both options are `should` clauses. You should boost the `text` clause and not the autocomplete clause.

Answer (score 2):

The score is a "relevance score" implemented internally by Mongo, I will say it is surprising to me that field length is not part of the score even if it's a "text" operand, I would personally expect it to be added in some form in the near future.

For now you could use a workaround to construct the score you want, for example you could use a `should` (or) expressions with a `phrase` operator combined with a boost score function, like so:

```
const searchOption= [
    {
        $search: {
            "compound": {
                "should" : [
                    {
                        "phrase":{
                            "query": "hi",
                            "path": "english",
                            "score": {"boost":{"value":5}} 
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: {
                            query: 'hi',
                            path: 'english',
                        },
                    },
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { $project: {  _id: 0, french: 1, english: 1, score: { $meta: "searchScore" } } },
    { $limit: 5 },
];

const result = await Greetings.aggregate(searchOption, { cursor: { batchSize: 5 } }).toArray();
```

Otherwise you could also just sort by `english` length combined with the score ( this is under the assumptions scores will be tied), obviously this is not a real sort as it assumes the top 5 results are the actual top 5 results you're expecting to get.

```
const searchOption= [
    {
        $search: {
            text: {
                query: 'hi',
                path: 'english',
            },
        },
    },
    { $project: {  _id: 0, french: 1, english: 1, score: { $meta: "searchScore" }, len: {$strLenCP: "$english"} } },
    { $sort : { score: -1, len: -1 } },
    { $limit: 5 },
];

const result = await Greetings.aggregate(searchOption, { cursor: { batchSize: 5 } }).toArray();
```

Comment: It's the only answer I found helpful. Thanks!