# MongoDB Atlas Search - why searching `Cameron Bri` returns the same search score for `Cameron Brink` and `Cameron Boozer`

Tags: mongodb, search, mongodb-atlas-search

Here is our MongoDB Atlas Search index definition:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": true,
    "fields": {
      "label": {
        "maxGrams": 7,
        "tokenization": "nGram",
        "type": "autocomplete"
      },
      "ptgc": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "sort": {
        "type": "number"
      }
    }
  },
  "storedSource": true
}
```

Not sure if the node.js route is needed for this question, but sharing what we are using in case it does provide some help:

```
router.get('/live-search/type/:type/text/:text', function (req, res) { // atlas search    
    try {
        let type = req.params.type; // one of 'all', 'team', 'player', 'conference'
        let text = req.params.text;

        // define the atlas search terms
        let filterQuery = type === 'all' ? ['conference', 'player', 'team'] : type;
        let searchTerms = {
            index: 'app_search_index',
            returnStoredSource: true,
            'compound': {
                filter: {
                    text: {
                        "query": filterQuery,
                        "path": "type"
                    }
                },
                must: {
                    autocomplete: {
                        query: `${text}`,
                        path: 'label'
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // define the query filters utilizing search above, plus sort & limit
        let queryFilters = [
            { $search: searchTerms },
            { $addFields: { score: { $meta: "searchScore" } } },
            { $sort: { sort: 1 } } // "sort" is 1: conference, 2: team, 3: player based on "type"
        ];

        // run aggregate pipeline and return
        db.our_table
            .aggregate(queryFilters)
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.length);
                console.log(data);
                res.json(data); 
            })
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error: ', error);
        res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: error.message });
    }
});
```

In the table we are searching, let's consider the 3 options `Cameron Brink: Stanford`, `Cameron Boozer: AUM`, and `Haley Cameron: Eastern Ill.`. All 3 options are `type: player`, therefore we can ignore the filtering and sorting by `type` as it does not come into play in this example.

We are searching the phrase `cameron bri`. The results - both `Cameron Brink: Stanford` and `Cameron Boozer: AUM` return a search score of `5.1432`, whereas `Haley Cameron: Eastern Ill.` returns a score of `5.22797`.

We need / strongly prefer that this search return a higher score for `Cameron Brink: Stanford` than it does for the other 2 options. Logically, I believe that `cameron bri` is a closer match to `Cameron Brink: Stanford` than it is to the other two options, but our index does not agree. It seems that the search is putting no stock into the `bri` of the search.

How can we modify our `MongoDB Atlas Search index definition` to better capture that `Cameron Brink: Stanford` is a better match for `cameron bri` than the other two options?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a workable solution, with the help of [Multiple documents having equal search score in MongoDB Atlas Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72332755/multiple-documents-having-equal-search-score-in-mongodb-atlas-search) - in particular the suggestion to define the label as both `autocomplete` and `text` in the index definition seems to be helping.

The compound part of the search in the route has been updated to:

```
'compound': {
    filter: {
        text: {
            query: filterQuery,
            path: "ptgc"
        }
    },
    should: {
        text: {
            query: `${text}`,
            path: 'label',
            score: { boost: { value: 1 } } 
        }
    },
    must: {
        autocomplete: {
            query: `${text}`,
            path: 'label'
        }
    }
}
```

This update to the compound search is different from the recommendation that both options be `should` causes, as I have left the `autocomplete` as a `must` clause.

`Cameron Brink: Stanford` gets a score of 8.795, second only to the option `Cameron Williams: Bridgewater (VA)` at 8.82, which is okay makes sense given the match of `bri` to `bridgewater` for this option.

`Cameron Boozer: AUM` returns the same previous score of 5.1432, same with `Haley Cameron: Eastern Ill.` returning a score of 5.22797 still.